# Salesforce : Application Administration

Tags: security, salesforce, force.com

Anyone can explain about this question ?

---

If the actors who will be using the applications are not determined before
the creation of application, which of the following will happen? Select any
two choices.
a. We will be unable to create reports and dashboards
b. Unauthorized users can access sensitive data
c. There will be no room for scaling the application to large users

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question is one [StackOverflows' rules](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) would consider good. Did you copy it from some certification exam maybe? ;) It's not exactly programming problem-related.

I'll flag it for mods but also try to attack it :P

An app is not much in SF world. Set of (default) tabs, that's it. If an user has no access to app that mentions tab XYZ it doesn't mean he can't access the tab from "all tabs" menu. The more important thing is the security setting on the object that says:

- tab hidden - meaning user with this profile is not even aware such object exists in the database, even if he has "Read" permission ticked

  - default off - accessible in "all tabs" menu
  - default on - visible by default in given app if said app is selected

  a. We will be unable to create reports and dashboards

No. Sysadmin will be able to see all data (and thus create reports) even if none of the apps includes this tab. What they talk about in this answer is controlled by object's "allow reports" checkbox (and if it's not ticked even being a sysadmin cannot help you). Normal users won't be able to make reports/run exisitng ones on given objects without having at least "Default off" + "Read" permission on the object in their Profiles.

```
b. Unauthorized users can access sensitive data
```

Yes? I can imagine this happening - you don't know which Profiles should access given object, you give Read access to all users, funny things happen. But then - by default nobody can see the data except people with "View all/Modify all" (like SysAdmins) so it's a bit weird answer. You'd have to explicitly go to each Profile and enable access...

```
c. There will be no room for scaling the application to large users
```

I don't understand this answer so I'm going to go with "no, bullshit" :D You can always grant access to given app (or object) per profile or even permission set if you have to, I don't see how this can become an issue...

```
d.
```

I'm missing 1 more answer, are you sure you copied complete question? I've never seen a SF exam question with less than 4 answers...

Disclaimer: I've never seen similar question on my exam or any practice exams. I've passed 201, 401 and 501 tests.